# Laravel 6 Error: Page not redirecting to the defined route

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, web, laravel-5

I've been stuck here for a while. I hope I can clearly explain the issue. I'm trying to have separate pages for admin and user. For that, I have created an admin middleware. Now when I login, it redirects me to the same page either its admin or user. I want it to go to admin dashboard when admin logs in and to the user home when user logs in. I hope the issue is clear.
Here is the **AdminMiddleware** code:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
      if(Auth::user()->user_type == 'admin') //If usertype is admin
    {
       return $next($request);
    }
    else {
        return redirect('home');
    }
    }
```

Here are the **routes** code:

```
    Route::get('/','HomeController@index');
//For Admin
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth','admin']], function() {

Route::get('/admin','HomeController@home_page');
Route::get('/users-list', 'UserController@users_list');

});
```

Here is the **HomeController** code:

```
public function index()
    {
return view('home', compact('currantWorkspace'));
}
```

I've added the Middleware path to **kernel.php** file.

I'll be happy to provide any other details if needed. Any solutions/suggestions will be highly appreciated.

**Edit**

I've tried this, but still issue.

```
    protected function redirectTo(){
  if (Auth::user()->user_type != 'admin') {
    return 'admin';
    //return redirect('/admin');
  }
  else {
    return 'home';
    //return redirect('/');
  }

}
```

I think the **redirectTo** function is not working, or not checking the if/else conditions

Comment: You also need to add the admin role condtion in LoginController.

Comment: @Sehdev Can you explain please?

Comment: There is a redirectTo property in LoginController. Set it blank protected $redirectTo; and add a redirecTo method in LoginController
 protected function redirectTo(Request $request)
{if(Auth::user()->user_type == 'admin') //If usertype is admin
    {
       return redirect('dashboard');
    }
    else {
        return redirect('home');
    }}

Comment: @Sehdev Tried, still both admin & user redirect to user home page

Comment: `redirectTo` is not a method, it's a property, can you try my solution?

Comment: @AndySong I tried, please check the comment below your answer

Comment: @MurtazaAhmad I have updated my answer let me know if it helps.

Comment: I think you forget to create user_type column in database or you forget to set it for this user as admin.The problem is that your if clause not get true.use dd(Auth::user()->user_type) befor if clause and see whats usertype is for this user.

Answer (score 0):

Change the route as follows.

```
Route::get('/','HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth','admin']], function() 
{
Route::get('/admin','HomeController@home_page')->name('admin.home');
Route::get('/users-list', 'UserController@users_list');
});
```

Change the redirect statement in middleware as

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
if(Auth::user()->user_type == 'admin') //If usertype is admin
{
   return $next($request);
}
else 
{
   return redirect()->route('home');
   OR
   return redirect('/');
}
}
```

Comment: Where to add the second statement? In homecontroller?

Comment: The page is crashing

Comment: try `return redirect('/');`

Comment: tried your updated answer, still both are redirecting to user home page

Comment: then your admin verification condition is false

Comment: What can be done with that? Any suggestions? Or anything else that you need?

Comment: Is there any column `user_type` in `users` table ?

Comment: check whether the column has an entry with admin or not.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create an 'if, else' statement in your login function like:

```
if(Auth::user()->user_type == "Admin"){
    return Redirect::route('dashboard'); 
}else if(Auth::user()->user_type == "Standard User"){
    return Redirect::route('home');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems, currently, the key thing is that the middleware you defined is not being called when anyone tries to log in.

To make it work I think you just need to add this to your `LoginController.php`

```php
    protected function authenticated()
    {
        if (Auth::user()->user_type == 'admin') {
            return redirect('dashboard');
        }

        return redirect('home');
    }
```

This method basically tells laravel what you want to do after the user is logged in.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I tried it, and it is giving me this error: 
Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::authenticated() must be an instance of App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Request, instance of Illuminate\Http\Request given, called in D:\Xampp\htdocs\Folder\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers.php on line 108

Comment: @MurtazaAhmad, you do not need the Arguments, you can remove those, I have updated my answer. can you try again?

Comment: @MurtazaAhmad, by  the way , the reason you get that error is that you have some import Collision.